# Error reading firebase object converted from firebase array, into React using findIndex()

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have amended a firebase structure from an array

```js
{
   "posts" : [
   {
      "code" : "BAcyDyQwcXX",
      "caption" : "Lunch #hamont",
      "likes" : 56,
      "id" : "1161022966406956503",
      "display_src" : "https://test1.jpg"
   },
   {
      "code" : "BAcJeJrQca9",
      "caption" : "Snow! ⛄️❄️ #lifewithsnickers",
      "likes" : 59,
      "id" : "1160844458347054781",
      "display_src" : "https://test2.jpg"
   },
   ]
}
```

to a 'flattened' object

```js
{
    "posts" : {
        "1161022966406956503" : {
            "code" : "BAcyDyQwcXX",
            "caption" : "Lunch #hamont",
            "likes" : 56,
            "display_src" : "https://test1.jpg"
        },
        "1160844458347054781" : {
            "code" : "BAcJeJrQca9",
            "caption" : "Snow! ⛄️❄️ #lifewithsnickers",
            "likes" : 59,
            "display_src" : "https://test2.jpg"
        }
    }
}
```

and now wish to refactor the following code to accommodate for the handling of an firebase object instead of an array:

```
 const { postId }  = this.props.params;
 const i = this.props.posts.findIndex((post) => post.code === postId);
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `findIndex` method, since you don't have an array anymore.

To find the **key** of the value, you'd use:

```
const posts = this.props.posts;
const key = Object.keys(posts).find((prop) => posts[prop].code === postId);
```

But why are you storing the posts under a timestamp when they already have a valid key? I'd recommend storing each post under that key:

```
{
    "posts" : {
        "BAcyDyQwcXX" : {
            "caption" : "Lunch #hamont",
            "likes" : 56,
            "display_src" : "https://test1.jpg"
        },
        "BAcJeJrQca9" : {
            "caption" : "Snow! ⛄️❄️ #lifewithsnickers",
            "likes" : 59,
            "display_src" : "https://test2.jpg"
        }
    }
}
```

Then you no longer need to lookup the index/key for a post, since you already have the key that you store it under.

Comment: Many thanks, @Frank. Your recommendations have been noted and adopted